# How to use Axios and get response from prams

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios

I am trying to query api but having issues. I need to send values for api to search to get a response.

Does not work but how I would like to setup

```
axios
        .get('http://localhost:3000/records/owner', {
          params: {
            owner: 'wxTWH8zqSwaIXPAVsjZoRCkvjx73',
            date: '2021-08-30',
          },
        })
        .then(function (response) {
          // handle success
          alert(JSON.stringify(response.data));
        })
```

Does work

```
        axios
        .get('http://localhost:3000/records?owner=wxTWH8zqSwaIXPAVsjZoRCkvjx73&data=2021-08-30')
        .then(function (response) {
          // handle success
          alert(JSON.stringify(response.data));
        })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You GET URL endpoint is **incorrect** in the first example. You have the `owner` parameter as part of your URL. Where as in your second example that you show works, the URL is pointing just to the `records` endpoint and `owner` is a param.

Instead try

```
axios
    .get('http://localhost:3000/records', {
      params: {
        owner: 'wxTWH8zqSwaIXPAVsjZoRCkvjx73',
        date: '2021-08-30',
      },
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      // handle success
      alert(JSON.stringify(response.data));
    })
```

Removing the `owner` parameter from your URL endpoint should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

You are making incorrect url in the first request - http://localhost:3000/records/owner

It should be axios.get('http://localhost:3000/records' {params: {owner: "data"} }